# No module named 'ensemble.voting' for Python 3.9 when pickle.load() is called

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pickle, python-3.9

I am facing this error when I run the command -

`pickle.load(open("model_name.plk", "rb"))`

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble.voting'**

Python v3.9

Pip v22.0.4

Comment: Do you have https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/ installed in your python environment ?

Comment: @Nathan, yes I do.
My observation is that I have trained my model using Python 3.6. Is that a problem?
Will I need to train my model under python 3.9 and then use pickle.load(..)? Will that work?

Comment: pickle is not meant to be used to transfer data across different python implementation. It can be done when choosing specific options but it is definitely not its purpose and can lead to errors

Comment: Look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format to pick how to deserialize it propely. There might be an issue also if the `sklearn` version changed and the code of `sklearn.ensemble.voting` changed. Do you have the exact same `sklearn` version installed as in python 3.6 ?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. 
The scikit-learn library version was the issue. I downgraded it to scikit-learn 0.21.3 and the code started working on Python v3.9, without model retraining.